# My header is shaking at button hover effect

Tags: html, css

Yo! I made this header from own mind (probably not a good idea to begin with) and added a little box that appears beside the icon when hovered over. When I then hover over it the whole header shakes a little bit while the transition is running and then it comes back and stays that way. However I don't want that shaky effect so if anybody would like to help me it would be much appreciated ^^

```css
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 100vh;
  border-right: 0.3vh solid #272727;
  box-shadow: 0.25vh 0.25vh 0.5vh #888;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header .buttons {
  transform: translateY(500%);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .buttons button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 8vh;
  height: 8vh;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.header .buttons button svg {
  width: 5vh;
  fill: #fff;
}

.header .buttons button .hover-box {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(-10vh) translateY(-5.5vh);
  background: #272727;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0.25vh 0.25vh 0.5vh #888;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 5vh;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.header .buttons button .hover-box p {
  font-size: 0.9vw;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(60%);
}

.header .buttons button:hover .hover-box {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateX(12vh) translateY(-5.5vh);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <center>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#"><button>
                    <svg height="5vh" viewBox="0 -16 512 512" width="5vh" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path style="fill: #272727" d="m497 269.988281h-136v-75c0-8.28125-6.714844-15-15-15h-75v-75c0-8.28125-6.714844-14.988281-15-14.988281h-75v-75.011719c0-8.28125-6.714844-14.988281-15-14.988281h-151c-8.285156 0-15 6.707031-15 14.988281v450c0 8.285157 6.714844 15 15 15h482c8.285156 0 15-6.714843 15-15v-180c0-8.28125-6.714844-15-15-15zm-15 90h-61v-60h61zm-91-60v60h-120v-60zm-361 60v-60h61v60zm0-90v-60h121v60zm0-90v-60h61v60zm91 120h120v60h-120zm210 90v60h-150v-60zm0-180v60h-150v-60zm-90-90v60h-120v-60zm-90-90v60.011719h-121v-60.011719zm-121 360h121v60h-121zm331 60v-60h121v60zm0 0"/></svg>
                    <div class="hover-box">
                        <p>The Wall</p>
                    </div>
                </button></a>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't see the effect you're describing. Which browser is this? I'm guessing Chrome.

Comment: Using *<center>* is not a good idea https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: I have opened it in Chrome and Edge and I cannot see the effect you are describing...

Comment: I can see it using safari. During the transition, Safari displace the svg icon 2px to the left for some reason. When the transition is done, the 2px replacement is being reset. Hence the "shaking" experience

Comment: I'm using chrome and I tried to delete the center tag aswell. No result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs on Safari. And as the comments suggested. Don't use center. Instead use flexbox or grid.

So removing the center tag solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong here. It is probably because of the browser.
What kind of browser are you using. Did you try using different ones? It does the same there?

Comment: Now when I tested on Edge it didn't react as in chrome... Any tips on how I solve that problem

Comment: @Kevlar2228 Gergios is right remove the center tag from html and use flexbox instead it.  I hope it helps.